# Drupal: change path to uploaded files

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I copied a site files to test host for further developement.

And I want uploaded files to be loaded from old host.

For example, files a re stored in drupal_folder/sites/default/files/ (example.com/sites/default/files).

I need this files to be accessible from other site (example.dev.com)

I mean I want to change path to all files on a new host (example.dev.com).

I tried to change path to all files in database with command

```
UPDATE `files` SET `filepath` = REPLACE(`filepath`, "sites/default/files/", "http://example.dev.com/sites/default/files/");
```

but URLs are like example.dev.com/http://example.dev.com/sites/default/files/ after this.

I hope it makes sence.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use ln to create the link to that directory if you are using linux.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm